# Efficient MySQL/Eloquent query to filter posts by more than 1 tag

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table

The setup consists of two tables (threads, tags) plus a pivot table (tag_thread) to allow the many-to-many relationship: One thread can have many tags, one tag can be used for many threads.

Attributes of the tables:

`treads: id, title`

`tags: id, name`

`threads: id, thread_id, tag_id`

Now I would like to filter through threads using not one but many tags. So I want to get all threads that are associated with all the given tags? Using only one I can easily do it via Laravel Eloquent using models like:

```
$filteredThreads = $tag->threads()->get()
```

I have managed to do it with two tags, but I feel like this is a very dirty and inefficent way to do it (especially considering that it goes through the whole list of ids to compare):

```
$threadIds = Thread::select('th.id')
        ->from('threads AS th')
        ->join('tag_thread AS tt', 'tt.thread_id', 'th.id')
        ->join('tags AS ta', 'tt.tag_id', 'ta.id')
        ->where('ta.name', $tag)
        ->pluck('id')
        ->toArray();

return $filteredThreads->whereIn('threads.id', $threadIds);
```

Can you think of a better solution? Thank you!

Comment: `JOIN tags AS ta ... JOIN tags AS tb ...`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get threads that have tag with one of the names defined in `$tagsNames` array:

```
$tagsNames = ['popular', 'cool'];
Thread::whereHas('tags', function($q) use($tagsNames) {
    $q->whereIn('name', $tagsNames);
})->get();
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you very much!  What if I want to get threads that have tags with all the names of `$tagsNames` though? To narrow it down.

Comment: @Hillcow in this case, you'll need to use `foreach($tagsNames as $name) { 
$q->where('name', $name); }` inside the `whereHas()` closure.

Comment: @Alexej Unfortunately your code does not work. It works with 1 tag, but not with 2. I think the problem is that after the first where() there is only this one name remaining. Using where() again with another name results in 0 results. Any other idea?

Comment: @Hillcow I think you're talking about the code in the second comment because the code in the answer works. If you are asking about the `foreach` one, try to do `$q = $q->where('name', $name);` instead of `$q->where('name', $name);`

Comment: @Hillcow looks fine. Are you sure the result is wrong? Did you try to hardcode both tags like `$q->where('name', 'tag1')->where('name', 'tag2');` without using the `foreach`? If it doesn't work, create multiple `->whereHas()` closures with just one tag in it by using `foreach` loop.

Comment: `$q->where('name', 'tag1')->where('name', 'tag2');` does not work either. I am pretty sure it's like I said: after the first where() there is no row left with any other name. It works though when I use multiple whereHas() hardcoded. How exactly do I use these with foreach? And does whereHas() create a new query for every time I use it?

Comment: @Hillcow I can't check this right now, but you can install Laravel Debugbar and look at actual SQL queries generated by Laravel. Just do something like `$threads = Thread::query();` then `foreach` with `$threads = $threads->whereHas(....);` in it. Then at the end `$threads = $threads->get();`

Comment: Very nice, didnt know about query () either. Will check later. Appreciate the help so far! :)

Comment: @Alexej so this worked liked you described - however, I don't know how to use it as a filter (setup by Laracasts forum series). I am doing `$thread = $this->builder->query()` but it's not working. I did not find anything about `query()` in Laravels documentation?